# Expo-Jest - Firebase - Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, jestjs, expo

I want to run tests on my React Native + Expo app components, but I can not get trough this error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | 
    > 2 | import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
```

Things I tried:

- Change my `import` to `require`
- Add lot of different `transformIgnorePatterns`

Any idea how to solve this?

**dev dependencies**

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.3",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "12.4.1",
    "babel-jest": "29.7.0",
    "jest": "29.7.0",
    "jest-expo": "49.0.0",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "3.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.1"
  }
```

**jest.config.js**

```js
const jestExpoPreset = require('jest-expo/jest-preset');

module.exports = {
  ...jestExpoPreset,
  transform: {
    '\\.[jt]sx?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [...jestExpoPreset.transformIgnorePatterns],
  setupFiles: ['./setupJest.js'],
  globals: {
    __DEV__: true,
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^react-native$': 'react-native-web',
    'expo-camera': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/mockExpoCamera.js',
    'expo-application': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/mockExpoApplication.js',
    'react-native-toast-message/lib/src/Toast': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/mockReactNativeToastMessage.js',
    'expo-barcode-scanner': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/mockExpoBarcodeScanner.js',
    'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Dimensions': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/mockReactNativeDimensions.js',
    'react-native-gesture-handler': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/mockReactNativeGestureHandler.js',
    'react-native-safe-area-context': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/mockReactNativeSafeAreaView.js',
  },
};
```

**Component.test.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import ScannerView from '../../../components/AddAnimal/ScannerView';

jest.mock('expo-constants', () => {
  return {
    expoConfig: {
      extra: {
        prod: false,
      },
    },
  };
});

jest.mock('react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons', () => ({
  // You can customize this mock as needed
  default: 'MaterialIconsMockedComponent',
}));

describe('ScannerView component', () => {
  test('renders correctly', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<ScannerView />);
    const exitButton = getByText('Kilépés');
    const torchButton = getByText('Vaku bekapcsolása');
    expect(exitButton).toBeTruthy();
    expect(torchButton).toBeTruthy();
  });
  test('exit button triggers navigation.goBack()', () => {
    const navigation = { goBack: jest.fn() };
    const { getByText } = render(<ScannerView navigation={navigation} />);
    const exitButton = getByText('Kilépés');
    fireEvent.press(exitButton);
    expect(navigation.goBack).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  test('torch button toggles flashlight', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<ScannerView />);
    const torchButton = getByText('Vaku bekapcsolása');
    fireEvent.press(torchButton);
    expect(torchButton).toHaveTextContent('Vaku kikapcsolása');
    fireEvent.press(torchButton);
    expect(torchButton).toHaveTextContent('Vaku bekapcsolása');
  });
});
```